# Singly linked list in C results in infinte loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define enter(x) scanf("%d", &x)
#define print(x) printf("%d",x)
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
} Node;

int main()
{
    int n;
    enter(n);
    Node *head, *tail, *ptr;
    head = tail = ptr = 0;
    while(n--){
        ptr = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        enter(ptr->data);
        ptr->next = 0;
        if(head==0){
            head = ptr;
            tail = ptr;
        }else{
            tail->next = ptr;
            tail = ptr;
        }
    }
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        print(ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After making `free()` the `ptr` again I assigned it the head address and then use this pointer to traverse the linked list. Now it generates an infinite loop and I can't understand what is wrong.

Comment: As I can see `ptr` points to the _tail_, so of you free it before checking the list, you'll hit UB.

Comment: Why do you think you need to call `free` at that point? The linked list still has references to the `ptr` so you must not `free` it, otherwise the linked list will be left with invalid pointer values in it.

Comment: remove `free(ptr); ptr = NULL;`  free instead in the last loop after e.g.` Node* tmp = ptr->next; free(ptr); ptr=tmp;`

Comment: @kaylum in layman terms if  memory allocated to ptr free it also makes free the memory allocated to tail by ptr which results in infinte loop.

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? We can't say that the result is always an infinete loop. Accessing freed memory is Undefined Behaviour. In C, UB means that we don't know what the result will be. It could be an infinete loop, it could be a crash, it could even appear to "work" or any other behaviour.

Comment: **Always a bug**: not testing the return value from scanf(). And how do you skip newlines or spaces in the input between numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define enter(x) scanf("%d", &x)
#define print(x) printf("%d", x)

typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;

int main() {
  int n;
  enter(n);
  Node *head, *tail, *ptr, *temp;
//initialize a pointer use `NULL` rather than 0
  head = tail = ptr = NULL;
  while (n--) {
    ptr = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    enter(ptr->data);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = ptr;
      tail = ptr;
    } else {
      tail->next = ptr;
      tail = ptr;
    }
  }
  //   free(ptr);
  //   ptr = NULL;
  ptr = head;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    print(ptr->data);
//traverse a node and then free it.
    temp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    free(temp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You should not directly free `ptr` since it will use in traverse.

There is a tool [valgring](https://valgrind.org/) to detect memory leak.